# Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.Find the remainder at $x=2006$ for the following conditions

Tags: functions

Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.The remainder when p(x) is divided by $x-1$ is $1$ and the remainder when $p(x)$ is divided by $x-4$ is $10$.If $r(x)$ is the remainder when $p(x)$
 is divided by $(x-1)(x-4)$, then find the value of $r(2006)$

My attempt is as follows:-

As it is given that when $p(x)$ is divided by $(x-1)$, then remainder is $1$.

So $p(1)=1$

As it is given that when p(x) is divided by $(x-2)$, then remainder is $10$.

So $p(4)=10$

Now it is given that when p(x) is divided by $(x-1)(x-4)$, then remainder is $r(x)$.

By the remainder theorem we can say that remainder would of degree one less than the divisor. So in this case $(x-1)(x-4)$ is of $2$ degree, hence $r(x)$ would be of $1$ degree.

So let's say $r(x)=ax+b$

$$p(x)=(x-1)(x-4)q(x)+r(x)$$
$$p(1)=r(x)$$
$$a+b=1\tag{1}$$

$$p(4)=r(4)$$
$$4a+b=10\tag{2}$$

Subtracting $2$ from $1$
$$-3a=-9$$
$$a=3$$

$$b=1-3$$
$$b=-2$$

$$r(x)=3a-2$$
$$r(2006)=3\cdot2006-2$$
$$r(2006)=6018-2$$
$$r(2006)=6016$$

So is this the correct method of solving this question or is there any better way to do this.

Comment: Your method is fine. But there are some typos.

Comment: An alternative is to not write $r$ in powers of $x$, but as the linear interpolation between the points $(1,1)$ and $(4,10)$. Namely, $r(x)=\frac{(x-1)}{4-1}r(4)-\frac{(x-4)}{4-1}r(1)$ and then just evaluate it at $x=2006$. For such a small problem there is no gain, but well, if the size of the problem increases it is good to know [how to efficiently do the evaluation of an interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).